# How I can save a char variable into a char* structure?

Tags: c, pointers, char, structure, factorial

I have the task to calculate the factorial of a number, saving into a structure and then print it.

Here is the code of the structure:

```
struct fact_entry
{                               /* Definition of each table entry */
    int n;
    long long int lli_fact;       /* 64-bit integer */
    char *str_fact;
};
```

After that it comes the next code. I had defined a long long int variable to calculate the factorial and there is no problem in saving this number in the first to elements of the structures, the print function works correctly. The problem is with the char *str_fact; variable, I wrote a code to change the int value into a char with sprintf, but after I assigned this value to the structure, in the next for cycle it only prints the last element calculated. If I try to print it inside the first for cycle everything works, but outside it only prints the last one.

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    int i;
    struct fact_entry *fact_table;

    if (argc != 2)
        panic ("wrong parameters");

    n = atoi (argv[1]);
    if (n < 0)
        panic ("n too small");
    
    if (n > LIMIT)
        panic ("n too big");

/* Your code starts here */
    // Allocate memory
    // Compute fact(n) for i=0 to n
    fact_table = calloc(n+1, sizeof(struct fact_entry));
    long long int f=1;
    char buf[20];
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0) { 
            f = f * i + 1;;
        }
        else{
            f=f*i;
        }
     
        sprintf(buf, "%lld", f);
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        fact_table[i].n = i;
        fact_table[i].lli_fact = f;
        fact_table[i].str_fact = buf;      
    }
    /* Your code ends here */

    // print computed numbers
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf ("%d %lld %s\n", fact_table[i].n, fact_table[i].lli_fact, fact_table[i].str_fact);
    }

    /* Your code starts here */
    // Free memory
    free(fact_table);
    /* Your code ends here */

    return 0;
}
```

How can I write the buf variable into the structure. I only can change the code between the `/*your code */`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> char buf[20];
> ...
> fact_table[i].str_fact = buf;
> ```

`str_fact` is a pointer, pointing to `buf`. You have `n + 1` elements, they all point to the same `buf`, they all print the last element as you see in your output.

You have to allocate memory for each `str_fact` so that it can store its own string. Remember to free the memory for that buffer as well.

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    ...
    //fact_table[i].str_fact = buf; *** remove this line
    fact_table[i].str_fact = malloc(strlen(buf) + 1);
    strcpy(fact_table[i].str_fact, buf);
}

for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    free(fact_table[i].str_fact);
free(fact_table);
```

Note that you are allocating `n + 1` elements. If you need `n` elements, then count up to `i < n` in all of the loops.